# How to Animate Tableviewcells in a ScrollWheel fashion?, Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, animation

I am attempting to animate my tableview so that it looks like a scroll wheel when scrolling up and down.
[Similar to this picture.](http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7305/9736338017_0698ce891f_o.png)

Here is the code I've made to animate the tableview when scrolling. Unfortunately, it does not resemble a scroll wheel in the slightest. So my question is, what changes do I need to make to get my desired result? Do I need to rewrite it completely? I assume I do not need SpriteKit for this?

```
       //setup the CATransform3D Structure
    var rotation:CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat((90.0*M_PI)/180), CGFloat(0.0), CGFloat(0.7), CGFloat(0.4))
    rotation.m34 = (1.0/(-600))

    //Define the initial state
    cell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10)
    cell.alpha = 0

    cell.layer.transform = rotation
    cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5)

    //!!!FIX for issue #1 Cell position wrong------------
    if(cell.layer.position.x != 0)
    {
        cell.layer.position = CGPointMake(0, cell.layer.position.y);
    }

    //Defines the final state after the animation
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.8, animations: {
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        cell.alpha = 1
        cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
    }, completion: nil)
```

[This is what the animation currently looks like](https://vimeo.com/74000302)

Comment: What does it look like currently? Please take screenshots and _show_, don't tell.

Comment: Unfortunately the site will not allow me to add images

Comment: So add a link to one.

Comment: Here. https://vimeo.com/74000302. Also now posted link in original post

Comment: Take a look at iCarousel. https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: @Paulw11 iCarousel doesn't actually have what I;m looking for. It looks like it runs collections through an animation, but I'm just trying to add an animation to my UITableView

Comment: iCarousel doesn't use a Tableview but it's data source and delegate methods are basically the same - You supply a `UIView` subclass instead of a `UITableviewCell` subclass and it doesn't have sections